# Typescript - narrowing a type union from function return types

Tags: typescript, type-inference, discriminated-union, type-narrowing

Why is it that Typescript cannot discriminate a type union whose types are from the return types of function, without explicitly declaring the return type on the function?

Here I do not specify the return values of the event creator functions and the union type cannot be narrowed.

```
enum EventType {
  FOO = "foo",
  GOO = "goo",
}

function createFooEvent(args: {
  documentId: number | null
}) {
  return {
    type: EventType.FOO,
    data: args
  }
}
function createGooEvent(args: {
  id: number
  isSelected: boolean
}) {
  return {
    type: EventType.GOO,
    data: args
  }
}

type EventArgType =
  | ReturnType<typeof createFooEvent>
  | ReturnType<typeof createGooEvent>

function eventHandler(event: EventArgType) {
  switch(event.type) {
    case EventType.FOO: {
      // Note that `event` contains `data` but `data`'s type is a union and has not been discriminated
      event.data;
      break
    }
  }
}
```

But if I specify the return types as follows then the union can be discriminated.

```
function createFooEvent(args: {
  documentId: number | null
}): {
  type: EventType.FOO,
  data: {
    documentId: number | null
}} {
  return {
    type: EventType.FOO,
    data: args
  }
}
function createGooEvent(args: {
  id: number
  isSelected: boolean
}): {
  type: EventType.GOO,
  data: {
    id: number
    isSelected: boolean
}} {
  return {
    type: EventType.GOO,
    data: args
  }
}
```

[Here is an example in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDkHlwWgdUgJQNIElwHFQFgBQeAzAVwDsBjAFwEsB7E0AUwA8BDAWwAcAbByEhgBQBKAN55QjEkTagAogDcGJCgBUAnhwagxuCRIBikSKAC8oAEQEaNcwBpxejEdMWA5tbsOAvngfFy1HSgZABODCwUDPrWCkoUAiwhrgDOAFzaDhIAJjRk0nGoWelSbABGDCGgAD6gUlxc3kIZunphFEQh9Dp6ehQaDOmxyuqaAHSGkPYtPVkRLOmJKZmgPi2rEv6UtPSh4ZEYMYrKCUlpzT1URbXS5SHLVMkAygw8lAxXpdY8LCSN560Mdqdf49PqaQZHVT9UZOSbLbJzBanZbrFa+FpgrRDCgAQSSIy0JmWNUQgI6JAJAB5MTQCMEwhEooc4gA+YmgUlAin9an9Wn0vYMA40bFs-AtTaBegMSEACR+WR4IQEMriELieNcBKa3T0yQA7lQKGQABYqyGjTE6+HBFjJLGQgnjIzpXU9CQgCA0SKgCgmiKgAAGquUgeCdAoLCoJGSQdmkbDpSIFDjc0DAHJY5jQA9QCxQKRtnmSFlQP7YyRvaBykpQFkHqEqGxo4ysjaJCGKKN4ywANzt6sMgDWNtRElRq1WeE9CBQj3RkqLzHY3AYKn1NGE-yU0jkjv6INAExclg8Ux6sJP7hs57R4o9YHA3q0foDfq0bXJvv6sf57-tAoRDQlSLnQsa5sw3BUGQRplhUWjyFmJpaMunA8HmnyKH4pBbEEuyMtEIqQicKSussOR5GwBRXCUtzVNc9SNGR0zfuCe5xE6Ey3gikbMe6da5PkyiFMUNwVPRdQNGsXiHp+wJur0-TqsM0JcTaPZIksLETthARFvh+zMscixnAplyiWUFT3E8LwMG8HxfOEvxrEIfGKWx2JOrC3F1oih4SOZ1yWXcLEBTZryRA5NDfM544yQpcldDamLKVCYzeepfkmSi3johI2bYpqBKmOynLklSNJ0gZTJEaypVkp0FV8lVDKGbVyhirpuHSnKCpKuaarscoRX9NaLEGkapoDcolqjf5toAZ5qkuvND5ej6r4psGkJhmQEZRjGqYJsWpaBj2GZZge5bVgwtb1skjbNiQrYDp23ZzP2oV6KUw6jjlax4KsQA).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because typescript does not infer the constant as the type by default: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

For example:

```
var a = 'test'
```

Typescript will infer type of `a` as `string` not as `'test'`.

You can fix it using `as const`:

```
var a = 'test' as const;
```

In this case `a` will be of type `'test'`.

Same for your code:

```
  function createFooEvent(args: {
    documentId: number | null
  }) {
    return {
      type: EventType.FOO,
      data: args
    };
  }
```

The return type of the function is `{type: EventType}` instead of `{type:'foo'}`.

Adding `as const` to the return type, will work as you expect [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgeTGQAoBKAbwFgAoRFMETRAUQDdkwoAVAT22SJqdeogBiBAogC8iAETA4cOQBpaoxAHFJM+QHMlq9YgC+tY6EiwEiCACdk6KMjFL2nKCXR29AZwBcQsb0ACZwEEweAJIhgYyYAEbIdogAPoiMuLjGJmRBIvQOUCB2SMIa9FD8yIHuXHwCAHQSBGoFoiFO6IHefsGmiOi+tgi+UADcORbg0PBI9o7Omm4cXF4+AfkaMLEZTEl2-TC+AMrI+NDIuwlK+OhgOXnlokUlZf2V1bWrPNWN2q0PohOlBuoMNv0TINhhBRhMpjRjFUBKwfgBBHwNQTSfrpABKyGKpSxAB5kcg4MBbA4nC4Vh4AHy4xAEolgUnkynUxbIZZwOpQJmIkSWWY2ZA-AAS9xC+DsJAlHm+HgxeixT36vgA7jAoBAABYKn6Ncka9r0CBDQQCrHNSSBZ4VRAAemdiAAcnBnIgoPqnIgAAaKrgBkZcdAwMDDAMg9ChhIgKCB2MBgDkw3JiGOg0Q4DmgzAIUQfuGYC9iCSnGBx3sMEwkdpISB9GDUEascm5tECRpAGsgWZ2oP6IPB0A)

```js
function exampleOne(){
  enum EventType {
    FOO = "foo",
    GOO = "goo",
  }

  function createFooEvent(args: {
    documentId: number | null
  }) {
    return {
      type: EventType.FOO,
      data: args
    } as const;
  }
  function createGooEvent(args: {
    id: number
    isSelected: boolean
  }) {
    return {
      type: EventType.GOO,
      data: args
    } as const;
  }

  type EventArgType =
    | ReturnType<typeof createFooEvent>
    | ReturnType<typeof createGooEvent>

  function eventHandler(event: EventArgType) {
    switch(event.type) {
      case EventType.FOO: {
        // event.data in this case will be {documentId: number|null}
        event.data;
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```